Adafruit QT PY ESP32-S3 Stuck in Bootloader Mode – How Can I Fix This?
I have an Adafruit QT PY ESP32-S3. While experimenting with configuration and UF2 files, the board got stuck in a reset loop. Pressing the reset (RST) button once makes the LED blink purple once, but it started blinking purple constantly after my attempts to upload files. Although I could upload Arduino code, it wouldn't execute due to the loop.
I followed the complete wipe steps from Adafruit's Factory Reset Guide. After reinstalling the UF2, the board is now only accessible in bootloader mode which is impractical because i need to upload code.
Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?
